How to Run a Method Asynchronously in a Reactive Chain in Spring WebFlux?
I'm working with Spring WebFlux and I need to perform an asynchronous task as part of a method that should not block the main response to the user. Specifically, I want to call an asynchronous method after completing the main task, but without delaying the response.
Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:
public Mono<ResponseDTO> publishPackage(RequestDTO requestDTO) {
    return publishPackageService.doSomething(requestDTO)
        .flatMap(responseDTO -> 
            doSomethingInAsync(requestDTO, responseDTO)
                .thenReturn(responseDTO)
        );
}

// Method that simulates an asynchronous task with a 5-second delay
public Mono<Void> doSomethingInAsync(RequestDTO requestDTO, ResponseDTO responseDTO) {
    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .then(); // Converts the delayed Mono<Long> to Mono<Void>
}


After this call completes, I want to execute doSomethingInAsync(requestDTO, responseDTO) asynchronously.
The doSomethingInAsync method should be non-blocking and not delay the main response.
Problem:
The doSomethingInAsync method is being executed, but it seems like it might be blocking the response or not running asynchronously as intended. How can I ensure that doSomethingInAsync runs asynchronously and does not block the response to the user?
Details:
publishPackageService.doSomething(requestDTO): Returns a Mono<ResponseDTO>.

doSomethingInAsync(requestDTO, responseDTO): Is an asynchronous method that I want to run without blocking the response.
Questions:
How can I ensure doSomethingInAsync runs in the background without blocking the response?

you use one of the doOn.... functions. For instance Mono.doOnComplete()

Where to use that? I didn't understand completely. Can you please help me understand that? @Toerktumlare

You have your regular chain, you then put doUpdateLayoutInAsync in a doOn block, and then you continue your chain after the doOn-block

@Toerktumlare I have posted this as an answer based on what you suggested. Is this what you actually suggested? Can you please take a look?

@Toerktumlare Can you please check the simplified version of the problem in the post itself?

why not try what you did before, using doOn...

As mentioned by @Toerktumlare, you can put the code you want to run asynchronously in a doOn operator. However, by default the code executed in doOn operators are run synchronously. If you want this to be run asynchronously, you can subscribe to the Mono.
So the code would be something like this
public Mono<ResponseDTO> publishPackage(RequestDTO requestDTO) {
    return publishPackageService.doSomething(requestDTO)
           .doOnNext(responseDTO -> doSomethingInAsync(requestDTO, responseDTO).subscribe());
}

// Method that simulates an asynchronous task with a 5-second delay
public Mono<Void> doSomethingInAsync(RequestDTO requestDTO, ResponseDTO responseDTO) {
    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .then(); // Converts the delayed Mono<Long> to Mono<Void>
}

